# matrix-vector-multiplication with hadoop: vector and matrix in different files

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to do matrix-vector-multiplication with hadoop. i've got a small working example now: there is only one input file containing the rows of the matrix always followed by the vector it is multiplied with. So each map-task gets one row and the vector from this single file.

Now I would like to have two input files. One file should contain the matrix and another one the Vector. but I cant think of a hadoop way to let the mapper access both files.

What would be the best approach here?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can read the vector in the setup method of mapper, and use it to do the multiplication.

Comment: There are several ways to do that For more detail you can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059725/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-inputs-with-multiple-different-mappers-in-hadoop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and most efficient solution is to read the vector into memory in the `Mapper` directly from HDFS (not as `map()` input). Presumably it is not so huge that it can't fit in memory. Then, `map()` only the matrix data by row. As you receive each row, dot it with the vector to produce one element of the output. Emit `(index,value)` and then construct the vector in the `Reducer` (if needed).

Comment: How will we able to get the resultant vector with correct positioning?If matrix is of large size around 2 HDFS block , we will get same index in these 2 mappers. How will we able to construct final vector?